# Obtaining asset information from wireshark pcap file

Tags: python, networking, network-security, pyshark

Which are the python packages that can be used to get a following information from a pcap file

1. Destination and source ip address
2. MAC Address of source and destination
3. Hostnames
4. Source Port and destination port.

Kindly suggest me a python package that can be used to parse a pcap to get the above information

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but have a look at `scapy`.

Comment: I was able to get all the information using pyshark except device type and hostname. Hostname details can be found from the DHCP packet but is there any way to get the hostname in statically assigned IP. Also is it possible to get the Device type whether it is a windows or apple or linux machine.  Could you please suggest some package for this